# Got a solution but still get an indexError

Tags: python

I have written this python code. When I run it I get an index error at the end;
I don't know why. I was wondering if someone could help me out.

The problem is to find the smallest positive number that is evenly divisible by all of the
numbers from 1 to 20. My analysis is correct but just the code at the end is giving me hard time.

```
def leastCommonDenominator(num1, num2):
    '''
        Returns the least common denominator of two numbers
    '''
    num2List = range(1,num2+1)
    if num1 < num2:
        for i in num2List:
            if (num1*num2List[i]) % num2 == 0:
                return num1*num2List[i]
    num1List = range(1, num1+1)
    if num2 < num1:
        for i in num1List:
            if (num2*num1List[i]) % num1 == 0:
                return num2*num1List[i]
    else:
        return num1

def leastNum():
    '''
        Prints the least number divisible
    '''
    myList = range(1,4)
    print myList
    num = 1
    for i in myList:
        num = leastCommonDenominator(num, myList[i])
        print num    

def main():
    leastNum()
```

Answer (score 2):

When you define `myList`, its value is (as you know):

```
myList = [1, 2, 3]
```

When you iterate, you are cycling through each of the elements (1, 2, 3), but when you call `leastCommonDenominator`, you are using the *index* of the list, not the element itself (i.e. in the first pass through, you aren't calling the first element of `myList`, you are calling `myList[1]`, which is the *second* element. This causes an `IndexError` on the final pass, because `myList[3]` is referring to the fourth element in the list, which as we can see does not exist (since `range` doesn't include the upper bound in its value). In order to fix, you should be able to do this:

```
num = leastCommonDenominator(num, i)
```

When you use the `for` loop like you are, you can simply use the values themselves. If you want to refer to the position of the elements, you can use `enumerate`, which returns both the index/position of a value and the value itself (this is more FYI - you don't need it here I don't believe :) ). For example:

```
for index, i in enumerate(myList):
    num = leastCommonDenominator(num, myList[index])
```

And you would get the same result.

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
for i in myList:
    num = leastCommonDenominator(num,i)
    print num
```

instead of

```
for i in myList:
    num = leastCommonDenominator(num,myList[i])
    print num
```

Here i is the iterator over the elements of the list.It is not over the index of elements.So you cannot use myList[i].On the other hand you can write

```
for i in range(0,len(myList)):
    num=leastCommonDenominator(num,myList[i])
```